# How to access a control that was created during page load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications

The page I have pulls information from the database and based off that it will either generate a text box or radio button on the page load.  The issue I am running into is that I am not able to utilize it later in the code behind.  I am wondering if its possible and how to make these accessible. For example, TextBox1 is created during the page load, then on a button click the code below will throw the error "'TextBox1' is not declared."

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.text = TextBox1.text
End Sub
```

Comment: When you create it, add it to a collection of controls (like a `Dictionary(Of String, Control)`). Then access it later by name. For example

Comment: You should avoid dynamically generating controls in the first place. It's easier to work with them if you declare both in the markup, and then selectively use one or the other. You can always adjust the .Visible property of the one not being used.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to put the controls in the ASPX markup. That allows you to reference it from code behind everywhere; however, if that is not an option for you and you need to handle everything in code:

```
Dim control as Control

Protected Sub Load()
    If ConditionForRadioButton Then
        control = new RadioButton()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click()
    If ConditionForRadioButton Then
        Dim radio = CType(control, RadioButton)
        ' do things with radio
    End If
End Sub
```

Add other cases for the other control types; if this is in some kind of collection you'd have to extrapolate this to work in that case, but the idea would be the same.